# Conexion de la base de datos sql server en wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

como puedo hacer para conectar la base de datos de SQL server en WordPress ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un buscador que se conecta a la base de SQL , mediante una conexión de PHP :

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! wp es un CMS... vos lo que buscas es como conectar php con sql server... empeza por buscar eso...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Lo que necesito es hacer la conexión a la base de SQL , Tengo la conexion echa con php
<?php

$nombreServidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "usuario1";
$contrasena = "123456789";
$nombreBaseDatos = "Envios";

try {

    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$nombreServidor;database=$nombreBaseDatos", $usuario, $contrasena);

    //echo "Conexion exitosa en el servidor $nombreServidor";

} catch (Exception $e) {
    //echo "Ocurrió un error en la conexion. " . $e->getMessage();
}


?>
.

Comment: el formulario de la foto busca lo que esta escrito en el input en la base de sql con un SELECT y lo muestra en pantalla

Comment: Me explico ,  quieres que te mande alguna foto del código.